# What is Allison's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, assembly

What is Allison's Algorithm and how does it aid in converting hex digits into ASCII characters?

```
;algorithm (found online)
ADD  AL, 90h 
DAA 
ADC  AL, 40h 
DAA
```

http://computer-programming-forum.com/46-asm/f85ec43b17441011.htm

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button says: 'This question does not show any research effort ...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have to understand the inputs & outputs to this sequence.

A hex digit is simply a 4-bit value, here provide in the AL register.  Thus, we're trying to convert a digit in the range 0x0 to 0xF into the corresponding ASCII character for hex digits; the output is also provided AL.

To convert these we need the following mapping, which is derived directly from the [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
  input     |               output
hex value   |    ascii char         hex value
  0x00      |     '0'                0x30
  0x01      |     '1'                0x31
  ...       |     ...                ...
  0x09      |     '9'                0x39
  0x0A      |     'A'                0x41
  ...       |     ...                ...
  0x0F      |     'F'                0x46
```

Note that in the ASCII encoding, '0' thru '9' are consecutive, and 'A' thru 'F' are also; however, there is a break in the run (between '9' and 'A'), so some conditional logic is required.

The code you're showing is better (i.e. shorter) than using conditional tests & branches to perform the same mapping.

As an exercise for the reader try putting 0x9 into AL and simulate the execution of the sequence using the following references (then try with 0xA, or 0xF in AL).

- [ADD](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2007/readings/i386/ADD.htm)
   note that ADD sets the Carry Flag (CF) and also the Auxiliary Flag (AF)
- [DAA](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2007/readings/i386/DAA.htm)
   note that DAA consumes both the Carry Flag and the Auxiliary Flag
- [ADC](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2007/readings/i386/ADC.htm)
   note that ADC works like ADD but also sums the Carry Flag (CF)

Comment: Thank you! However, I am unsure whether to loop the code or use larger registers (if possible) in the code.

Comment: This code morphs the AL register from a hex digit into an ASCII character representing the hex digit.  To convert a 16-bit value, say in BX, into a hex string, you could use a loop of 4 (maybe unrolled), extracting into AL consecutive 4-bit nibbles from BX, and, of course, doing something with the output (e.g. creating a string).